Add a role assignment between two different resource groups using ARM
'Resource Group 1' has user assigned managed identity and active storage accounts. 'Resource Group 2' has passive storage accounts. Now, current ARM template has the definitions for the user managed identity and active storage accounts and within the nested deployment, it has definitions for passive storage accounts which are deployed in 'Resource Group 2'.
Now I want to add role assignments between user assigned managed identities and storage acccounts. Role assignments between user assignment managed identity and active storage accounts which are in the same resource group are deploying fine. But I am unable to deploy role assignments between user assigned managed identity in resource group 1 and passive storage accounts in resource group 2.
I have tried adding cross resource group role assignments within the nested deployment where passive storage accounts are defined but I am getting template validation error that the passive storage account is not defined in the template.
ARM template

  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2023-01-01",
      "name": "[variables('activeStorageName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('storageLocation')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "properties": {
        "defaultToOAuthAuthentication": false,
        "allowCrossTenantReplication": false,
        "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_0",
        "allowBlobPublicAccess": false,
        "allowSharedKeyAccess": true,
        "networkAcls": {
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "virtualNetworkRules": [],
          "ipRules": [],
          "defaultAction": "Allow"
        },
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
        "accessTier": "Hot"
      }
    },
    {
      "condition": "[parameters('shouldDeployPassiveStorage')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "PassiveStorageDeployment",
      "resourceGroup": "[variables('PassiveResourceGroupName')]",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "parameters": {},
          "variables": {},
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
              "apiVersion": "2023-01-01",
              "name": "[variables('passiveStorageName')]",
              "location": "[parameters('passiveRegion')]",
              "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
              },
              "kind": "StorageV2",
              "properties": {
                "defaultToOAuthAuthentication": false,
                "allowCrossTenantReplication": false,
                "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_0",
                "allowBlobPublicAccess": false,
                "allowSharedKeyAccess": true,
                "networkAcls": {
                  "bypass": "AzureServices",
                  "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                  "ipRules": [],
                  "defaultAction": "Allow"
                },
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
                "accessTier": "Hot"
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
              "apiVersion": "2022-04-01",
              "name": "[guid(concat(subscription().id, variables('passiveStorageName'), parameters('managedIdentityName'), 'Storage Blob Data Contributor'))]",
              "scope": "[format('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{0}', variables('passiveStorageName'))]",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('passiveStorageName'))]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe')]",
                "principalId": "[reference(resourceId(variables('activeResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('managedIdentityName'))).principalId]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-30",
      "name": "[parameters('managedIdentityName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2022-04-01",
      "name": "[guid(concat(subscription().id, variables('activeStorageName'), parameters('managedIdentityName'), 'Storage Blob Data Contributor'))]",
      "scope": "[format('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{0}', variables('activeStorageName'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('activeStorageName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe')]",
        "principalId": "[reference(resourceId(variables('activeResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('managedIdentityName'))).principalId]"
      }
    }
  ]

Below is error message I got while deploying
Code: InvalidTemplate

Message: Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/passiveStorageName' is not defined in the template


Without sharing the ARM Template it is hard to support you. Generally I would recommend you to use bicep as it is easier to use and diagnose.
But speaking about your issue, you should be able to create a nested deployment
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/deployments?pivots=deployment-language-bicep which contains the RBAC assignment and takes the resource id of the resource as input.

@JulianHüppauff, thanks for your response. I have updated the ARM template and error. Can you please take a look.

The arm tag is for the ARM CPU architecture. I'm guessing you wanted azure-resource-manager here instead, so I added it. Please edit if this is not correct. In general, please check the description of a tag before using it. Welcome to the site!


Add a role assignment between two different resource groups using ARM

The main issue to seems to be with the way we try to deploy using same RG in which the managed identity is used and also the way we nested the managed identity in the variables
Even though the managed identity was from direct RG we can refer it directly as mentioned in the below configuration.
ARM configuration:
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "managedIdentityName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "testvksb"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "passiveResourceGroupName": "vksb-rg2",
    "passiveStorageName": "passivestoragevkk",
    "userAssignedIdentityApiVersion": "2018-11-30"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2022-04-01",
      "name": "[guid(concat(subscription().id, 'passivestoragevkk', 'testvksb', 'Storage Blob Data Owner'))]",
      "scope": "[format('/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{2}', subscription().subscriptionId, variables('passiveResourceGroupName'), variables('passiveStorageName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b7e6dc6d-f1e8-4753-8033-0f276bb0955b')]",
        "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('vksb-rg1', 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('managedIdentityName')), variables('userAssignedIdentityApiVersion')).principalId]"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Deployment:


Refer:
Azure ARM Role Assignment different Resource Group - Stack Overflow by 4c74356b41 
Assign Azure roles using Azure Resource Manager templates - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Learn
Adding Role Assignments to Two Different Resource Groups using ARM: Active Storage Accounts in ResourceGroup1 vs. Active Storage Accounts in ResourceGroup2 
